# How to force PDOException / reach catch block (php)

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

Here is my basic php code:

```
try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=name;host=localhost", $db_username, $db_password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //run queries etc...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //handle and log error appropriately 
}
```

Is there an easy way to reach the catch block or force a PDOException so that I can test and/or debug the page in the event that a database error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to reach the catch block

Yes. Like in any other case, just force an intentional error.

> or force a PDOException

Just like any other exception, `throw new PDOException('test');`

> } catch (PDOException $e) {
> //handle and log error appropriately
> }

This is **wrong** way of handling errors. Create and install [an exception handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). While you have to keep `try..catch` for another purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The throw new PDOException is just what I was looking for. I will also look into exception handler. Could you give me a quick explanation of the difference between try..catch and handler?

Comment: try..catch have to be used to handle the **error itself.** Most of time you don't need it at all. While to handle the error **message** a handler is sufficient and enough. Written once it will serve ALL your queries without any additional code. Catch your errors only if you have to do something beside just logging - say, to delete a file, to rollback a transaction etc.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I mostly just need to log the error and redirect the user.

Comment: Let me advise you not to redirect, but show the error page in place. SEO engines do not like redirects. It's better to send 500 HTTP status and show some generic error page.

Comment: Your constructive feedback is appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: just to add; you can log your error, stop your script and even redirect (not that you should) with just using an exception or error handler

Comment: @Lan just to add: you can log your error, stop your script and send 500 HTTP error (what you should) **without** using any handler or whatever else extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a fake (bad) connection.  If your db name is 'name', put 'name1'.

-EDIT-  What's with the downvote?  It works...  Would've commented, but I can't yet.

Comment: Hey thanks! That was almost too easy =) PS: downvote wasn't me.